# How to display content of collapsed div from another webpage

Tags: html, href

I have LIMITED knowledge with webpage development. I have access to several pages on this server but NOT to the page that I am trying to display data from, which I'll call Page A. Page A has all of its info in Collapsed divs. If you are ON Page A, all you have to do is click on the heading and the info displays. But I want to be able to expand a particular div from a remote page.

If I use this command, it flashes the div content on the screen but then goes back to showing all of the collapsed divs.

`<a href="http://www.brevardcounty.us/NaturalResources/Watershed/PollutionPrevention#YardWaste&style=display: block;">Yard Waste </a>`

The code basically looks like it just changes the display setting from "none" to "block" if it is clicked on so I'm not sure why it doesn't work for me to just pass the style variable.

I'm probably just in over my head but I thought I would ask.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry. My code sample wasn't showing up. I corrected it.

Comment: They're using `javascript` to **expand** and **collapse** blocks, no chance to make it work with `anchors`

Comment: Is there a way to write a script on the pages that I do control that can pass the onclick command?

Comment: No, you can for example write a browser `bookmarklet` that allows you to inject your custom script on their page on **the client side**, but every visitor that clicks on that link targeting their page must have your `bookmarklet` already installed on his browser. So I think It's not worth the hassle.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll just keep after them to change the format of their page. Or I'll create another page that has all of their info. I appreciate your help.